# Graphql SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: node.js, graph

I know there are many questions with the similar Title but this one is different I believe. I am trying to learn nodejs stuff and I figured out Graphql could be a nice point to start. Here is my problem:

When I try
`import { GraphQLServer } from 'graphql-yoga';` it gives the error but the code below works perfectyl:
`const { GraphQLServer } = require('graphql-yoga')`

I don't want to fix the bug with the easy way and go on. I want to learn the fundamentals. Thanks for your help.

Dependencies I used:

"dependencies": {
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"graphql-yoga": "^1.18.3",
"nodemon": "^2.0.4"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this npm package does not work with the kind of ES6/ES7 syntax we use for our projects. Therefore, you need babel to convert this syntax into ES5 syntax.

To solve this, you need to do 3 things

1. Install Babel

   npm i babel-cli babel-preset-env
2. Create and configure a .babelrc file in the root directory of your project

   {
   "presets":[
   "env"
   ]
   }
3. Create a "start" script in package.json that utilizes the conversion power provided by Babel to run your JS file (mine was 'index.js' in the 'src' folder inside the project directory)

   "scripts":{
   "start" : "babel-node src/index.js"
   }